What is crawling on my curtain in the kitchen?
I found one of these crawling on my curtain. 

Most likely a small beetle - which one would need better photos and a general location in the world as there are many many thousands (IIRC about 400,000) of beetle species world-wide.

I found out it's a biscuit beetle, a pest. Thank you for the advice: I'll be more specific next time.
